# Is it possible to get access to the speaker signal on Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl, audioflinger

Sending audio to the speaker for playback on Android is easy, but is it possible to get a copy of the *actual* final digital signal? Let's say I have 2 apps running "MyApp" and "SomeOtherApp". My app sends audio to the speaker, but so does "SomeOtherApp". "SomeOtherApp" is not my app - it's a 3rd party app. Is it possible to get a copy of the mixed audio signal which is played to the speaker by the OS? That is, the audio signal which is a mixture of the speaker signal from my app and the speaker signal from "SomeOtherApp".

To summarize: I am looking for a way to hook into the low-level audio path (HAL audio stream out - after mixing!) so I can get a copy of the "final" speaker signal (in real-time). Optimally, I would also like to hook into the low-level microphone path, but that's less of a concern right now.

Comment: Got this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495644/how-to-capture-output-stream-of-audio-in-android

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the short answer is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495644/how-to-capture-output-stream-of-audio-in-android).

Longer one is [kinda](https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/record-play-and-visualize-raw-audio-data-in-android). And [sorta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676142/record-android-audio-output). But not really, as far as I know. Option 1: it might be a problem with respects to privacy. (not really a good option) Option 2: nobody thought it was needed, so did not build it into the system. Option 3: the amount of trouble shooting when programmers use the wrong source is just not worth it.

*edit* - You can, of course, record the [input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.asr).

Answer (score 1):

Checkthis one [google example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/audio-echo)

Usage :

> App will capture audio from android devices and playback on the same
>   device; the **playback on speaker will be captured immediately**

*

Comment: Looks promising, but due to: *to verify it, it is recommended to "mute" the playback audio with a earspeaker/earphone/earbug so it does not get looped back.* I think it uses the mic and a fast(er) way to play said audio. Would be nice to have some input of someone who has used this.