# Is it possible to programmatically listen to the speaker output in Android?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

Is it possible to capture the speaker output in Android?

This would be for the purpose of determining, when listening to the microphone input, which sounds were generated from other apps and which originated from the user.

This is essentially to create an acoustic cancellation filter on the output of other apps, so their sounds don't interfere with the microphone input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to capture the output stream, per this post :

[How to capture output stream of audio in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495644/how-to-capture-output-stream-of-audio-in-android)

Unless there has been some change since six months ago, when this question was answered.

However, a workaround (which does not look good) is mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

As of Android 10 you can use the AudioPlaybackCapture API for audio playback capture.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture